# param is missing or the value is empty: - RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've researched this thoroughly but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm writing a model spec and everything seems routine but I keep getting this error - `param is missing or the value is empty: subscriber` - I really don't know what else to say? I'll post my code and error for more clarity.

CONTROLLER:

```
 def subscriber_params
  params.require(:subscriber).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number)
 end
```

SPEC:

```
 require "rails_helper"

 describe SubscribersController do
 include Devise::TestHelpers

 let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
 let(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }

 it "creates a new comment" do
  sign_in(user)
  comment = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment)

  expect { post :create, comment: comment }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
  end
 end
```

ERROR:

[image]

Let me know if you need to see anything else. Thank You!

Comment: `subscriber_params` defines that your controller expects `params[:subscriber]` to be present. But in your specs you only pass in a `comment`. You need to pass in a `subscriber` too. For a more precise answer you might want to post the `create` method of that controller (and all `before_action`s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your strong params you are requiring a subscriber but you are not sending one with your request.  Try the following:

```
  require "rails_helper"

 describe SubscribersController do
 include Devise::TestHelpers

 let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
 let(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }

 it "creates a new comment" do
  sign_in(user)
  comment = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment)

  expect { post :create, subscriber: subscriber, comment: comment }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
  end
 end
```